# gitlab socket connect : Connection refused

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

while I am trying to reconfigure my gitlab instance, I am getting this error.
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure works fine but when i try to launch gitlab I see 502 Error and when i tail the logs I see this -

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
{"correlation_id":"xWNXeQFn6Ua","duration_ms":0,"error":"badgateway: failed to receive response: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: connection refused","level":"error","method":"GET","msg":"error","time":"2020-10-28T23:22:16Z","uri":"/favicon.ico"}
{"correlation_id":"xWNXeQFn6Ua","duration_ms":1,"host":"gitlab.systems","level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.1","referrer":"https://gitlab.systems/users/sign_in","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:0","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":502,"system":"http","time":"2020-10-28T23:22:16Z","uri":"/favicon.ico","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36","written_bytes":2940}
```

I have checked and the socket file does exist at the location /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket. I don't know what's wrong but it was working before and suddenly stopped working. Is it something related to permission issue?

```
root@gitlab-serv # pwd
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets
root@gitlab-serv # ls -lrt
total 0
srwxrwxrwx. 1 git git 0 Oct 28 23:25 gitlab.socket
root@gitlab-serv #
```

**Gitlab Version -
Version:        13.3.6-ee**

Any guidance is appreciated because I am totally stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Basically when i changed the permissions I did it recursively using -R option so 2 files `puma.id` and `puma.state` owned by root but ideally they should be managed by user `git` by which we run the Gitlab and that's why these files were not accessible.
I changed the permissions and reconfigure it and it worked. Just posting it so if anyone else faces the problem they should know what to look for

Comment: Would be nice if you provide full path for files. I can not imagine where to locate those files. Also, you can accept your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The files are located within the Gitlab container under `/opt/gitlab/var/puma`. The commands reach and change them are:

```bash
docker exec -ti gitlab bash # replace gitlab with your container name
cd /opt/gitlab/var/puma
chown git:git puma.pid puma.state
exit
```